# Need to replace the object value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to replace the object value, below is the code where I need to replece object value. But here I don't want entire array length, directly want to replace `Mon` value. `weekday`is dynamic/ known.

```
array = [{
        Mon: "0",
        Tue: "1",
        Wed: "0"
    },
     {
        Mon: "0",
        Tue: "1",
        Wed: "0"
    }
]


var weekday = "Mon";
array[0].weekday = "1"
```

Comment: You are looking for "weekday" not "Mon" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap with `[]` instead of dot notation

```js
array = [{
    Mon: "0",
    Tue: "1",
    Wed: "0"
  },
  {
    Mon: "0",
    Tue: "1",
    Wed: "0"
  }
]


var weekday = "Mon";
array[0][weekday] = "1"

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer...